# Uploading bootloader on ATmega328P SMT package using Arduino Uno

Tags: bootloader

I have been trying to upload bootloader on ATmega328P SMT package on a custom PCB using Arduino Uno as ISP, I was quite successful.

I have Googled a lot and have tried numerous ways, sometimes I was able to successfully upload the bootloader, but I am not able to upload the sketch am getting "avr sync error".

- What kind of bootloader should I use for this particular package?
- How should I upload the sketches into the chip?

Comment: Are you using a serial converter to upload the sketch?

Comment: I removed the chip on arduino uno and tried uploading sketchs using tx ,rx and reset pin.

Comment: Are you using a bootloader for the Uno, e.g. Optiboot?

Comment: I am using optiboot(arduino duemilanove or nano w/atmeg328) as bootloader i also tried optiloader.I was able to upload the bootloader on both the methods

Comment: Well, okay, but you need to behave like an Uno, since you're using an Uno as the frontend.

Comment: Do you have a crystal of the same frequency on your board?  Try making a serial echo sketch and uploading that using ISP (instead of bootloader) to test that your board works and the serial connection works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had success with bootloader of the Arduino IDE.
I used to have some trouble uploading sketches, but I solved them by doing this:

1. If the atmega is already soldered in a pcb and you have a pull up resistor, or something else connected to the reset pin, disconnect it. reset pin must be free.
2. Connect the tx, rx and rst pins of your atmega to your arduino.
3. Press the Upload button in the Arduino IDE and see the leds tx,rx in your arduino, just after the first blink, press the reset button, after that both of the leds should start blinking and in the end your code should be uploaded.

Comment: I tried removing the pull up resister on my pcb still my atmega is not talking back the rx pin is not blinking

Comment: hmm, I missed something obvious... you are powering the atmega with 5v, right?

Comment: yes am power it up with 5v from the arduino board